# How do weapon statistics relate to game play?

Tags: payday-2

I'm interested to know what the weapon stats mean in the game. I have made some assumptions, but I'm curious to know if there is any official line on them.

Take the following example of adding a short barrel to my rifle.

[image: car-4 short barrel]

So does this mean that with reduced accuracy I'll have less chance to hit an enemy, so more weapon spread. What about mobility? Is a higher value better? Does it affect weapon swapping? Reloading? What benefits are there of lots of noise?

There doesn't really seem to be anything in game to understand what the stats actually mean in real terms.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So it turns out in the install directory of the game, for me, `E:\Steam\steamapps\common\PAYDAY 2` there is a PDF which details the game. It's got a handy page on the stats!

[image: Pdf snip]

Comment: I don't have such PDF file. Could it be a pre-order bonus?

Comment: Possibly, it's called `The Guide of Bain.pdf`

Comment: @3ventic No this is not from the pre-order but from the Career criminal edition

Answer (score -3):

If you are looking for a practical commentary on weapons in payday 2, take a look at this [payday 2 weapons guide](http://www.altergamer.com/payday-2-general-weapons-guide/)

Comment: Please add the relevant information to your answer here.  Saves people a click, and ensures your answer is still valid, even if the website goes down.

Comment: I've given this answer a downvote because it does not address the question. The question related to the weapon stats, which having read the article are not even covered, making this article irrelevant to this question. Sorry.